# "Operation system not found" after fresh Ubuntu Server installation

Tags: ubuntu, boot, system-installation

I have just freshly installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 amd64 on my Laptop and did the most basic setup possible. Then when the installation was successful i was prompted to remove my installation medium (USB stick) and rebooted the system.

When the system then booted from the harddrive i just get the single line "Operation system not found" (not a typo, it actually says "Operation"). I then did the procedure once again and eyeballed that i correctly pick my harddrive to format and it went the same way. I can't do anything after restarting.

I then also tried to use Boot-Repair-x64 to repair the GRUB bootloader and it all went fine and sayd it repaired grub but in the end nothing changed. I'm trying for a full 5 hours now and I don't know what i should do. The Laptop is definitely working as i had my windows server as well as a suse-server running fine on there. Laptop is a Dell XPS 15 with an Intel i7-2650U (i think).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sounds like the EFI boot partition is missing, and the error message is raised by the UEFI/BIOS.

Comment: Run this script and edit the output into your question: https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/

Answer (score 1):

I have no expertise in this topic whatsoever, but I have struggling with the same problem for the past day. I also confirm to have a working computer (HP Elitebook 8460p, Intel Core i5) and it did not want to boot in the installation on the hard drive, giving me error of `“Operation system not found”`.

The solution that finally worked for me (though, I cannot really provide explanation why) is installing Ubuntu Legacy server - different install images can be found on Ubuntu official site: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-legacy-server/releases/20.04/release/

I am wondering if the same install would be successful also at your end. It would be nice to know what is causing the issue with installing the new Live version.

Comment: this worked for me as well with an old dell xps laptop